# Accessing a private method in a overridden public method

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, access-levels

I am currently having some issues with accessing a private method from a overriden public method.

My situation is like this: I have a compiled .dll file which consist basically of this

```
public class OriginalHandler
{
    public virtual void Request()
    {
        RedirectIfConditionIsFulfilled()
        this.PeformRequest()    
    } 


    protected virtual bool PeformRequest()
    {

    }

    private static void RedirectIfConditionIsFulfilled()
    {

    }

}
```

I need to alter the method `PeformRequest()`, So i make a public class, which inherit `OriginalHandler` and override the method as such:

```
public class ModifiedOriginalHandler : OriginalHandler 
{

    protected override bool PeformRequest()
    {

    }

}
```

To ensure that this method doesn't violate an "impact" scope, I have to ensure that it only get evaluated on certain sites, 
We use this to ensure that HttpRequestProcess ONLY impact the desired site using this

```
namespace Sitecore.Sharedsource.Pipelines.HttpRequest
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Assert = Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert;
    using S = Sitecore;

    public abstract class SiteSpecificHttpRequestProcessor: S.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestProcessor
    {
            public abstract List<string> _sites;


            public sealed override void Process(S.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
            {
                Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

                if (S.Context.Site == null || !this._sites.FirstOrDefault(S.Context.Site.Name))
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.DoProcess(args, this._sites.FirstOrDefault(S.Context.Site.Name));
            }

        protected abstract void DoProcess(S.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args, string);
    }
}
```

So include my `ModifiedOriginalHandler` to include this

```
 public class SiteSpecificModifiedOriginalHandler: SiteSpecificHttpRequestProcessor
 {
Public override List<String> _sites => new[]
{
    "www.only.com"  , "www.boat.com"
};


public virtual HttpContext GetHttpContext()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current;
    }

    public override void DoProcess(HttpRequestArgs args, string)
    {
        var mediaRequest = new ModifiedOriginalHandler ();
        var context = GetHttpContext();
    var site = Sitecore.Context.Site;

        if (site == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (string != null)
        {
            mediaRequest.Request(context);
        }
        else
        {
            OriginalHandler baseClass = mediaRequest;
            baseClass.Request(context);
        }
    }
 }
```

This Is where I am having a problem, I can from the SiteSpecificModifiedOriginalHandler not call the protected method `PeformRequest`,
but can call the public method `Request` which internally calls the desired function, so I make an override function, 
to ensure that the original is not being called but my modified version

```
public class ModifiedOriginalHandler : OriginalHandler 
{

    protected override bool PeformRequest()
    {

    }

    public override void Request()
    {
        RedirectIfConditionIsFulfilled()
        this.PeformRequest()    
    }        
}
```

Which is where I am having my problem, `RedirectIfConditionIsFulfilled` is a private method, 
and I can in no way make this method call as such.  I could in my overridden function remove this call, but that would 
require `RedirectIfConditionIsFulfilled` to be removed, which would alter the original functionality, which i don't want to do.

So how do i overcome this?

How do i access a private method in a overriden public method?

Comment: If you want to be able to access it from inherited classes, why not make it `protected` instead of `private`? That's what it's for.

Comment: That's quite a lot of code to read through... if you can compact it without losing any key information that would be very helpful. Also, you may want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DaveInCaz This should be a pretty MVCE,  I am trying to explain how and why i ended up with my solution..

Comment: If your question is fundamentally "How do i access a private method in a overridden public method?" then the rest is basically context; the context explains why you have need of this, but is accessory to the specific technical requirement. The easier it is to read, the more / better answers you may receive. (That said, you are getting some answers :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to `OriginalHandler` implementation  then make the derived class a nested one:

```
class A {
    private void Foo() { }
    protected virtual void Bar() { }

    public class B: A {
        protected override void Bar() {
            Foo(); \\ legal } } }
```

If you don’t then barring reflection there is no way to access from an external type a private member of another type.

Comment: I just endded reimplementing the same method in  my `ModifiedOriginalhandler`

Comment: Not sure why it was implemented at Private to begin with, it should have been a protected.

Comment: @Anita Ask whoever implemented the method, he should know better than anyone. Assuming the design is wrong can be dangerous and side skipping a method that the base class is expecting gets called is a good path to disaster. Unless you really know the method has no side effects that you are failing to reproduce in exactly the same way you can be screwing up the invariants of the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a `private` method from an inherited class. (But you know that.)
But your question didn't give any reason why your method shouldn't be `protected`, which would expose it to inherited classes.

What you're describing is exactly why `protected` exists.

A nested class will work, but I don't recommend it unless you want every single inherited class that needs the `private` method to be nested inside the base class. What if some of those inherited classes have their own `private` methods and even more inherited classes need to access those? You'd have to nest classes inside your nested classes.

Comment: The question here is why a derived class needs access to a private member of the parent type. Its either a bad design of the base class, a bad idea in the derived class or a mechanism meant to restrict access to the private member  to a tightly controlled group of derived types; nested ones (nested types inheriting the enclosing type is actually a very useful and elegant pattern). Assuming any of those scnearios is premature.